# dplyr no longer in library

Tags: r, macos, dplyr, installation, macos-mojave

I had dplyr and tidyverse installed and used for various tasks and projects. Since the update of my mac OS to 10.14.1, R-Studio no longer finds the package dplyr and tidyverse, but other parts of the tidyverse still work.

I have R Studio Version 1.1.419 installed on a macbook also, the same problem all code using parts of dplyr result in error messages.
The error message is:

> Warning in install.packages :
>     **installation of package 'dplyr' had non-zero exit status**

`install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies=TRUE)` worked with some warnings:

> **tar: Failed to set default locale**

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't very clearly stated. Also, I'm not sure how it relates to programming.

Comment: Please include all the error message from R terminal and (if possible) the output of this command: `sessionInfo()`

Comment: here is the output of the command sessionInfo: R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     


[1] compiler_3.5.1 R6_2.3.0       tools_3.5.1    yaml_2.2.0

Comment: I am not sure also, my programs did work properly before updating the mac OS . Now I get the error message: Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called 'dplyr'

Comment: I checked the list of installed and loaded packages, as dplyr was no longer on the list, I tried to reinstall both "dplyr" and "tidyverse" but both resulted in the error message shown above

Comment: sorry, if I did not answer the questions correctly, but I am not very sure how to do this.

Comment: In the meantime I found that dplyr was loaded  but not compiled. What I don´t understand why the older version was no longer available with the install packages and secondly why only installing  dplyr resulted in an error message all other components of tidyverse seem to be there

Comment: @AloesR2512: I don't think it's the full error message. Can you restart your R session then run the following line from the R console? `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: If you have any error, copy and paste everything then add to your question

Answer (score 0):

take to https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2002

I had a some-what similar problem:

Everytime I started R Studio, the following message appeared:
`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lme4’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘Rcpp’ Error in .requirePackage(package) : unable to find required package ‘lme4’`

I tried many things, including loading the "dplyr" package, and I got this message:
`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘Rcpp’`

After reading this post, I tried installing the "Rcpp" package, and it worked:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.14.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 4358936 bytes (4.2 MB)
>   downloaded 4.2 MB
>   package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   The downloaded binary packages are in
>   C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpA1EPax\downloaded_packages

Then when I tried loading the "dplyr" package, I got the following message:

> library(dplyr)
>   Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
>   The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
>
> ```
> filter, lag
> ```
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
>
> ```
> intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
> ```
>
> Warning message:
>   **Installed Rcpp (0.12.14) different from Rcpp used to build dplyr (0.12.11).
>   Please reinstall dplyr to avoid random crashes or undefined behavior**.

(the last part explains where the problem was, I think!)

Finally, I installed the latest version of the "dplyr" package. I was also able to load the "lme4" package.

I hope this helps..

---

Hi, I do it this steps and very good function R